# WooCommerce 'Product Image' area missing in admin panel

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce 4.41 and the 'product image' area has disappeared in the admin panel, leaving me unable to upload new images. Images previously uploaded are still in place on front end.
I have disabled all plugins other than WooCommerce but still have the same problem. Can anyone help please?

I am using WordPress 5.5.1 and latest version of theme Enfold.

Answer (score 1):

The product image metabox should be in the right sidebar. Assuming there are no errors on your site the only thing that could explain the missing metabox is that the 'Product image' checkbox isn't checked in the 'Screen Options' dropdown. You can find the 'Screen Options' dropdown, with the 'Product image' option, on the order edit screen at the top right.

[image]